# Prioritize files in Tiered Storage on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: storage

I'm running Windows 2012 R2 with Tiered Storage. Is there a way to prioritize files and ensure they always are located on the faster drives?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, this is supported.
It's called pinning

```
Set-FileStorageTier –FilePath <file> -DesiredStorageStier (Get-StorageTier -MediaType SSD)
```

After pinning a file, you need to "optimize" the volume in order for the change to take effect.

```
Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter **<driveLetter>** -TierOptimize
```